# Cassandra QueryLogger introduces NoHostAvailableException

Tags: java, spring-boot, cassandra

I have a spring boot application, where I have used the pattern of extending AbstractCassandraConfiguration to bootstrap Cassandra. It alls works beautifully. I now want to turn on query logging, so i have attempted to implement this pattern:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/7312#issuecomment-358448437

I do this by updating my AbstractCassandraConfiguration implementation to:
1. Be a @Configuration class 
2. Adding the Bean QueryLogger Bean

But then at runtime, I start getting the NoHostAvailableException.

As the before and after code are v similar, ill just paste it all and indicate the new, breaking code.

I can feel connection is getting corrupted, but also feel my pattern is so standard, not sure what is going on!!! Any tips appreciated. Thanks

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.config.AbstractCassandraConfiguration;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.config.SchemaAction;

import com.datastax.driver.core.AuthProvider;
import com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster;
import com.datastax.driver.core.PlainTextAuthProvider;
import com.datastax.driver.core.QueryLogger;

@Configuration   // **** NEW ****
public class CassandraConfig extends AbstractCassandraConfiguration {

  @Value("${spring.data.cassandra.contact-points:placeholder}")
  private String contactPoints;

  @Value("${spring.data.cassandra.port:0000}")
  private int port;

  @Value("${spring.data.cassandra.keyspace-name:placeholder}")
  private String keySpace;

  @Value("${spring.data.cassandra.username}")
  private String username;

  @Value("${spring.data.cassandra.password}")
  private String password;

  @Value("${spring.data.cassandra.schema-action}")
  private String schemaAction;

  // removed all the @Override getters for above props

 // **** NEW ****
 @Bean
 public QueryLogger queryLogger(Cluster cluster) {
    QueryLogger queryLogger = QueryLogger.builder().build();
    cluster.register(queryLogger);
    return queryLogger;
   }
 }
```

Exception:

[dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.cassandra.CassandraConnectionFailureException: Query; CQL [SELECT * FROM my_table;]; All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: cassandradb01.AAA.test.XXXX.com/10.18.51.15:9042 (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.BusyPoolException: [cassandradb01.AAA.test.XXXX.com/10.18.51.15] Pool is busy (no available connection and timed out after 5000 MILLISECONDS))); nested exception is com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: cassandradb01.AAA.test.XXXX.com/10.18.51.15:9042 (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.BusyPoolException: [cassandradb01.AAA.test.XXXX.com/10.18.51.15] Pool is busy (no available connection and timed out after 5000 MILLISECONDS)))] with root cause

Comment: Seems to be goosing my connection pool. I'm using Slices, and when I configure my query, such that it can be returned in 1 slice, I get no errors - and cql even logged! When I update my query such that it requires 2 slices, it breaks with above error..

Comment: Can you let me know the table definition and the no of rows in the table? May be you are trying to retrieve lots of data and the query is timing out.

Comment: @Damo did you find the issue? I am also facing this issue.